# PHP - Comparing double to a string is weird?

Tags: php, string, compare, double

I'm seeing some weird behavior in php when comparing a double to a string and was hoping someone could explain to me what is going on.

If I declare $num = 0.333;
and then test 
$num == '0.333', 
this comes out as true. If I then add 1 to $num and then subtract 1, then $num == '0.333' comes out as false. If I then cast $num as a string, the comparison goes back to being true. Why is it doing this?

Here's a sample:

```
<?php
  $num = 0.333;

  //returns 0.333 double Yes
  echo $num, ' ', gettype($num), ' ', $num == '0.333' ? 'Yes' : 'No', '<br />';

  $num += 1;
  $num = $num - 1;

  //returns 0.333 double No
  echo $num, ' ', gettype($num), ' ', $num == '0.333' ? 'Yes' : 'No', '<br />';

  $str = (string)$num;

  //returns 0.333 string Yes
  echo $str, ' ', gettype($str), ' ', $str == '0.333' ? 'Yes' : 'No', '<br />';
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're right, it's weird to compare floats and strings ;)

Comment: Yeah why are you doing this?...

Comment: I have to add some numbers together, and then convert the decimal part to a fraction if it's a common fraction. So there here I added 1.333 and -1, and the fraction conversion does a string compare. I'm now casting as a string before doing the string compare which 'fixes' the issue, but I was curious as to why this was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a floating point.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php says:

> never compare floating point numbers for equality.

The `==` compares for value, but 'across' types: one of the types must be converted before it can actually be compared. And this will result in comparison of floating point variables. That's why after doing a seemingly balanced action (+1 and -1) you're getting different results.

Comment: Ahh i see, that makes sense. Why does gettype() return "double" then?

Comment: Just so I understand, so in the first comparison, before adding 1 to $num, $num is a double, but the addition and subtraction converts it to a float?

Comment: No, a double is a floating point type, just like a "float" but then more 'numbers' :D

Answer (score 1):

For comparing value AND type in PHP, you need to use 3 "=". like :

```
$num = 333
$num === 333 => true
$num === '333' => false
```

See here for more details http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

A possible way to compare Float, is to use the method indicated in the comments of php.net regarding [floats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#103679) :

```
<?php 
$number1=number_format($float1,2,'.',''); 
$number2=number_format($float2,2,'.'''); 
if($number1!=$number2){ 
 echo 'do correction here!'; 
} 
?>
```

But apparently, there isn't a definitive, best way to do it (or I didn't found it). Some convert the float to String, other does the code I just wrote.

As you like ;)

Comment: You should be carefull with that `$num === 0.333`. As the manual says, don't compare for equality with floatings..

Comment: But while it is true, I don't think this actually solves any of @bachs problems :D

Comment: Now, it should be more accurate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take away point: use === instead of == to avoid type coercion.

The reason is that in the first instance $num is a double, but it is also equal to the string '0.333'.

Using === shows that the double 0.333 isn't the same as the string '0.333'.

The second one has done some addition, now the double isn't exactly 0.333 anymore, so it isn't the same as a string to to floating point inaccuracies.

The third one has cast 0.333 to a string, which is of course the same as the string.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't gettype($num) return 'float' in the second case then?

Comment: A double is a float with more precision.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a float for which trailing digits are a problem.

One think you can do is convert the float to a string and take the first x characters (ie if you have a string '.333' that you're comparing it to, convert the float to a string and take the first four characters), or you can floor the float to the proper decimals before comparing it.

Comment: To expound on this, note the result of `var_dump($str - $num)`, which on my system evaluates to "float(5.5511151231258E-17)".  For more information, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems.

Comment: Thanks. That makes total sense. Is there another function to use other than gettype() which would return 'float' in the second case instead of 'double'?

Answer (score 0):

To compare two float or double use http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php